# Call a function & return output to an external DLL in c#

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I have a project which reads an external DLL through reflection and

```
  System.Reflection.Assembly BuildDll = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + BuildDllName);
  Type BuildWindow = BuildDll.GetType(BuildFormType);
  System.Reflection.MethodInfo constructors = BuildWindow.GetMethod("Initialize");

  lMethod = BuildWindow.GetMethod("Submit");
  TypeUserControl = Activator.CreateInstance(BuildWindow);
```

In this code I load the DLL and read its two methods Submit(to call this method to perform some actions) & Initialize(to pass the data required by DLL)

Now I have to return a function's result from my code to the DLL on a button event of that external DLL, there is a method in my code which returns the desired integer value

```
 int GetValue(string id, int key)
```

In the external DLL a delegate is been defined as

```
 private System.Delegate _BaseFunction;
 public Delegate BaseFunction
 {
    set { _BaseFunction= value; }
 }
```

On button Click event of external DLL result needed to be displayed

```
 private void btnBaseInvoke_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           object[] parameters = new object[2];
           parameters[0]= Convert.ToString(txtParam30.Text.Trim());
           parameters[1]= Convert.ToInt32(txtParam31.Text.Trim());
           object obj = _BaseFunction.DynamicInvoke(parameters);
           MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(obj));
       }
```

What I am not getting is how will I initialize this delegate in my code & pass these parameters to my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The external DLL is a bit annoying in using a `System.Delegate` instead of a more specific delegate, but this is still very easy to solve.

To turn your `GetValue` method into a delegate, you can just do something like this:

```
var delegate = (Func<string, int, int>)GetValue;
```

That's it :)

Since you're using reflection (Do you have to? Isn't there an interface you could use instead or something? Do you have to load the assembly dynamically in the first place?), you may need to manually convert the resulting delegate to `Delegate` (which is just another cast), but I'm not sure if even that is necessary. Just call the setter on the property and pass it the delegate and you should be fine.

Comment: Hi Luaan, thanks for the reply. Yes I am loading this assembly dynamically. Actually I am providing a frame for a client's custom control ( totally developed by them and i just needed to initialize & load into my module) which needs a result from my project module. Can you please guide me as where i can put your solution in my example mentioned above . Is this delegate going to be called by external dll in his code? If so how will me module bind this delegate?

Comment: You've posted all the relevant code in your question. Just call the setter on `BaseFunction` - that's what the external DLL is invoking.

Comment: Yupp, got the same. Thanks alot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `MethodBase.Invoke Method (Object, Object[])`?

Maybe [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) will help you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this will not help as Invoke method is going to be called from external dll which in this case won't be possible.